# How can I write a query to carry a remaining balance of hours forward for load leveling a schedule?

Tags: common-table-expression, sql-server-2019

I have a query result with a total amount of hours scheduled per week in chronological order without gaps and have a set amount of hours that can be processed each week. Any hours not processed should be carried over to one or more following weeks. The following information is available.

```
Week | Hours | Capacity
1       2000     160
2        100     160
3          0     140
4        150     160
5        500     160
6       1500     160
```

Each week it should reduce the new hours plus carried over hours by the Capacity but never go below zero. A positive value should carry into the following week(s).

```
Week | Hours | Capacity | LeftOver = (Hours + LAG(LeftOver) - Capacity)
1        400     160          240 (400 +   0 - 160) 
2        100     160          180 (100 + 240 - 160)
3          0     140           40 (  0 + 180 - 140) 
4         20     160            0 ( 20 +  40 - 160) (no negative, change to zero)
5        500     160          340 (500 +   0 - 160)
6          0     160          180 (  0 + 340 - 160)
```

I'm assuming this can be done with cte recursion and a running value that doesn't go below zero but I can't find any specific examples of how this would be written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are not wrong, a recursive common table expression is indeed an option to construct a solution.

Construction of recursive queries can generally be done in steps. Run your query after every step and validate the result.

1. Define the "anchor" of your recursion: where does the recursion *start*?
   Here the start is defined by `Week = 1`.
2. Define a recursion iteration: what is the *relation between iterations*?
   Here that would be the incrementing week numbers `d.Week = r.Week + 1`.

Avoiding negative numbers can be resolved with a `case` expression.

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  Week int,
  Hours int,
  Capacity int
);

insert into data (Week, Hours, Capacity) values
(1, 400, 160),
(2, 100, 160),
(3,   0, 140),
(4,  20, 160),
(5, 500, 160),
(6,   0, 160);
```

**Solution**

```
with rcte as
(
  select d.Week,
         d.Hours,
         d.Capacity,
         case
           when d.Hours - d.Capacity > 0
           then d.Hours - d.Capacity
           else 0
         end as LeftOver
  from data d
  where d.Week = 1
union all
  select d.Week,
         d.Hours,
         d.Capacity,
         case
           when d.Hours + r.LeftOver - d.Capacity > 0
           then d.Hours + r.LeftOver - d.Capacity
           else 0
         end
  from rcte r
  join data d
    on d.Week = r.Week + 1
)
select r.Week,
       r.Hours,
       r.Capacity,
       r.LeftOver
from rcte r
order by r.Week;
```

**Result**

```
Week  Hours  Capacity  LeftOver
----  -----  --------  --------
1     400    160       240
2     100    160       180
3     0      140       40
4     20     160       0
5     500    160       340
6     0      160       180
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=94287bdfdb157610a8fe3b33bba68d86) to see things in action.

Comment: this does the trick and is what I came up with as well after some deliberation. I was posting my own answer and yours came in while I was writing it. I left my own answer below but I'm marking yours as correct since it's simpler to follow for anybody else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a few CTEs then a recursive CTE and got what I needed. The capacity is a static number here but will be replaced later with one that takes holidays and vacations into account. Will also need to consider the initial 'LeftOver' value for the first week but could use this query with an earlier date period to find the most recent date with a zero LeftOver value then use that as a new start date, then filter out those earlier weeks in the final query.

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = (SELECT MAX(FirstDayOfWorkWeek) FROM dbo._Calendar WHERE Date <= GETDATE());
DECLARE @EndDate date = DATEADD(week, 12, @StartDate);
DECLARE @EmployeeQty int = (SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM Employee WHERE DefaultDepartment IN (4) AND Hidden = 0 AND DateTerminated IS NULL);

WITH hours AS ( 
/* GRAB ALL NEW HOURS SCHEDULED FOR EACH WEEK IN THE SELECTED PERIOD */
SELECT c.FirstDayOfWorkWeek as [Date]
  , SUM(budget.Hours) as hours
FROM dbo.Project_Phase phase
  JOIN dbo.Project_Budget_Labor budget on phase.ID = budget.Phase
  JOIN dbo._Calendar c on CONVERT(date, phase.Date1) = c.[Date]
WHERE phase.CompletedOn IS NULL AND phase.Project <> 4266
  AND phase.Date1 BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
  AND budget.Department IN (4)
GROUP BY c.FirstDayOfWorkWeek
)
, weeks AS (
/* CREATE BLANK ROWS FOR EACH WEEK AND JOIN TO ACTUAL HOURS TO ELIMINATE GAPS */
/* ADD A ROW NUMBER FOR RECURSION IN NEXT CTE */
SELECT cal.[Date]
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cal.[Date]) as [rownum]
  , ISNULL(SUM(hours.Hours), 0) as Hours
FROM (SELECT FirstDayOfWorkWeek as [Date] FROM dbo._Calendar WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate GROUP BY FirstDayOfWorkWeek) as cal
  LEFT JOIN hours on cal.[Date] = hours.[Date]
GROUP BY cal.[Date]
)
, spread AS (
/* GRAB FIRST WEEK AND USE RECURSION TO CREATE RUNNING TOTAL THAT DOES NOT DROP BELOW ZERO*/
SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
  , rownum
  , Hours
  , @EmployeeQty * 40 as Capacity
  , CONVERT(numeric(9,2), 0.00) as LeftOver
  , Hours as running
FROM weeks
ORDER BY rownum
UNION ALL
SELECT curr.[Date]
  , curr.rownum 
  , curr.Hours
  , @EmployeeQty * 40 as Capacity
  , CONVERT(numeric(9,2), CASE WHEN curr.Hours + prev.LeftOver - (@EmployeeQty * 40) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE curr.Hours + prev.LeftOver - (@EmployeeQty * 40) END) as LeftOver
  , curr.Hours + prev.LeftOver as running
FROM weeks curr
  JOIN spread prev on curr.rownum = (prev.rownum + 1)
)

SELECT spread.Hours as NewHours
  , spread.LeftOver as PrevHours
  , spread.Capacity
  , spread.running as RunningTotal
  , CASE WHEN running < Capacity THEN running ELSE Capacity END as HoursThisWeek
FROM spread
```